# How to randomize a click

Tags: python, automated-tests

I am creating a automated test in python with selenium webdriver and cant figure out how to randomly select a checkbox.
Its creating a question that can have a pre question. Pre question is under a checkbox and i need to sometimes select it and sometimes not to select it but cant figure out how to do it.

Comment: You should provide some code so that we can see what you tried and did not manage to solve.

Comment: Note that test framework usually don't provide random inputs methods, because randomness is considered going against testing repeatability. Since you have a simple checkbox here, if both cases are relevant, you could test both cases. Otherwise, save yourself headaches and just pick a single value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python's random library to randomly enable/disable the checkbox

```
import random

def should_enable():
    return random.choice([True, False])
```

Then, you can just pipe the output of that over to the checkbox.

Comment: If this answer helped you, please mark it as correct by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thanks